# Node.js + express : rewrite url path

Tags: node.js, url, url-rewriting, express

I'd like to know if it's possible to rewrite an url with express.

I actually have this code :

```
var http, express, app;

http = require("http");
express = require("express");
app = express();

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded())

.post("/ajax_login", function (req, res) {
    "use strict";
    http.get({ host: "localhost", port: 8080, path: "/users/" + req.body.email + "/email" }, function (resp) {
        resp.setEncoding("utf8");
        resp.on("data", function (data) {
            json = JSON.parse(data);
            if (json.password.password === sha1(req.body.password)) {
                res.render("home.ejs"); 
            } else {
                res.render("login.ejs", { email : req.body.email, error : "password is not good" });        
            }
        });
    });
})

.get("/login", function (req, res) { 
    "use strict";
    res.render("login.ejs");
})

.listen(3030);
```

I call /ajax_login from a form :

```
<form method="post" action="/ajax_login">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Connection</button>
</form>
```

The problem is : when I call /ajax_login, after res.render my HTML code on my browser is changed, but the url still /ajax_login.

How I can change this URL ?

I know the javascript solution :

```
window.history.pushState("", document.title, "/login");
```

But, I'd like to know if a solution exist from the server.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should add more information about the way you call your server and, also, what do you want to do clearly ? You want to call your server from your JS and change the url after the call ? I'm not sure to understand. Dont forget that the `history`API is HTML5 so this method won't work for old browser like IE 9. You should take a look at [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

Comment: Unless you are making AJAX calls (and it seems that you are not), the convention is for the server to send a redirect to the browser with res.redirect("home.ejs") to force the URL change as you are describing. This also prevents users from resubmitting login data if they were to hit refresh on their browser.

Comment: I've added some information about the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add an error to the request locals, redirect to login, and then check if an error exists when rendering the login page.

```
.post("/ajax_login", function (req, res) {
    "use strict";
     ...

    if (password && email IS OK) {
        res.locals.errorMSG = "password is not good";
        res.redirect("/login"); //redirect vs render
    } else {
        res.render("home.ejs");
    }

})

.get("/login", function (req, res) { 
    "use strict";
    res.render("login.ejs", {error: res.locals.errorMSG || null});
})
```

[res.locals](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals)

[res.redirect](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect)